# Is defacing the airline logo of a wrecked airplane illegal?

Tags: faa-regulations, airline-operations, accident-investigation, regulations

I was listening to [episode #25](http://www.hellointernet.fm/podcast/25) of the Hello Internet podcast where Brady Haran mentioned that it's not unheard of for airline employees to rush to their own airplane's respective accident scene to deface the logos and registration numbers painted on the airplane's wings and fuselage. This is apparently done to reduce the damage to the airline's reputation. Below is an picture of the same from an [alleged account](http://www.theaustralian.com.au/news/world/thai-airways-tries-logo-cover-up-after-a330-300-skids-off-runway/story-e6frg6so-1226715235550?nk=452313ce6ca44bbb59b1db3d2a47be5b) of Thai Airways defacing the logo on a crashed (but still very intact) airplane.

[image]

So is there any law regarding whether this can be done? Could defacing the logo end up hampering the air crash investigation?

Comment: It doesn't look like it's forbidden by the ICAO, so it would depend on jurisdiction. Do you want to limit your question to China?

Comment: This is a very common practice. It helps prevent the media from identifying the airplane and making a big deal out of the crash - hurting the companies image. I remember coming to my flight school one day and there was a totaled Cessna 172 on a trailer with the tail number and flight school logo taped over. I never heard a word of it in the news, so this practice definitely works - probably better for flight schools than airlines.

Comment: @raptortech97 Not necessarily, but I would be interested to know about whether the jurisdiction differs over there.

Comment: Personally, I don't see the point in hiding the logo when you got your company colors sprayed all over the craft, never mind that you can probably just look up all relevant information on the arrivals page for that air port's website.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs that would be true for most of the members of Aviation SE but IMO 90% of the public won't bother to check out which airline it is just from the pictures.

Comment: @shortstheory I'm mainly talking about journalists, who will share that info with the 90% that doesn't check.

Answer (score 14):

In the US (you tagged your question FAA) it would most likely be illegal. [49 CFR 830.10](http://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?c=ecfr;sid=bdbd83b90630a32f49bc9b59cc3b8605;rgn=div5;view=text;node=49:7.1.4.1.12;idno=49;cc=ecfr#se49.7.830_110) says (note that the NTSB investigates US accidents, not the FAA):

> (b) Prior to the time the Board or its authorized representative takes custody of aircraft wreckage, mail, or cargo, such wreckage, mail, or cargo may not be disturbed or moved except to the extent necessary:
>
> (1) To remove persons injured or trapped;
>
> (2) To protect the wreckage from further damage; or
>
> (3) To protect the public from injury.

It seems highly unlikely that painting over logos would be justified for any of those reasons. On the other hand, this wording leaves the question open of what might happen *after* the NTSB takes custody, and in theory an airline could do it with permission.

Personally, I find it hard to see how this would help the airline because the story would be all over the news anyway, but laws and attitudes vary widely in different parts of the world.

Comment: After the NTSB takes custody they can give permission, on the basis that the logo (or more importantly, hull under/around it) isn't important to the investigation. The rules are to prevent accidental or deliberate destruction of evidence

Comment: This is done in cases where it is _not_ “all over the news”. A runway excursion requiring evacuation with no injuries or maybe one or two sprained ankles will get a mention in local newspaper (and on [AvHerald](http://avherald.com)) but that's about it. It is also usually only done when it is on an airport where the travellers can see it.

Comment: Also, pictures posted on the internet are forever.  From a PR point of view it makes perfect sense to minimize the possibility of adverse publicity.

Comment: @JanHudec I'd buy this as a PR save if it weren't for the fact that the rest of the livery is usually a pretty good indication whose plane it was -- Google `Airline livery red purple orange gold` and you'll find that the jet above is *strikingly similar* to a Thai Airways paint scheme. If a news reporter wanted the airline name that's a pretty trivial way to get it. But hey - if it makes the airline feel better!

Comment: Well, @voretaq7, I was wondering myself why they only blackened the logo and number as it still made the owner easily identifiable especially given there were more aircraft of the same airline around. In the other cases the aircraft was repainted more thoroughly. Like in [this](http://avherald.com/h?article=45d25cc2) case.

Comment: @voretaq7 That's the thinking behind the last sentence in my answer: in some parts of the world most people still get their news from newspapers and internet access is (relatively) limited and/or controlled. In that environment I can imagine a state-funded company (like Thai Airways) locking down the reporting, even if in a more tech-savvy and open society it looks pointless. But I'm not exactly an expert on media trends and press freedom, so I may be way off track on this.

Comment: @Pondlife: I don't think it would slow down serious reporters anywhere, but this kind of accident rarely makes front page; more like short column on third page. It's more to limit panic among travellers who see it and perhaps tweet/facebook/googleplus/… it (and never bother to look anything up).

Comment: Most people can read (at least in developed countries) and can retain names (e.g. company names), while a smaller fraction will recognise the livery. For example I personally can recall the "Asiana" accident but I don't know how they paint their aircraft.

Comment: @voretaq7 However, if I (an amateur) accidentally see the photo above, I'll remember these two things: 1st there was a plane with crashed front wheel, 2nd it was purple and white. OTOH, if I see a large **THAI** sign over it, I'll much more likely remember the following thing: Thai planes are not safe. This small trace in my brain can influence my decisions, whence their sales.

Comment: Would covering the tail by a large white poster be considered as "disturbing"? It's an action that is easily revertible.